# TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, fs

I'm writing a project in VUE that uses 'fs', and here's my code.

```
 async Upload(file){
            let fs = require('fs');
            console.log(file);
            console.log(this.dialogImageUrl);

            try {
                // use 'chunked encoding'
                // let stream = fs.createReadStream(this.dialogImageUrl);
                // let result = await this.client.putStream(file.file.name, stream);
                // console.log(result);

                // don't use 'chunked encoding'
                let stream = fs.createReadStream('./views/1.txt', {encoding:"utf8"});
                let size = fs.statSync('./views/1.txt').size;
                let result = await this.client.putStream(
                    '1', stream, {contentLength: size});
                console.log(result);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            };
            // console.log(file)
        }
```

However, the following error was encountered in use:

```
 TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function

    at _callee3$ (TestViews.vue?6930:97)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
    at new Promise ()
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at VueComponent.Upload (TestViews.vue?6930:85)
```

Comment: Isn't Vue a client-side framework that runs in the browser? How can it possibly use `fs` which is a module built into *Node.js* and not browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your Vue code is running in a web browser. There is no `fs` module available in web browsers. `fs` is a Node.js module, which is only available in a Node.js process (on your server or workstation).

File access on browsers is extremely limited for security reasons. But if you're trying to read a file from your server, you can do that with ajax, typically (these days) using `fetch`:

```js
const response = await fetch("./views/1.txt");
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
}
const text = await response.text();
// ...use the text here...
```